# Jquery Image Gallery Next Button

Tags: jquery

Can't seem to get this jquery gallery working. I've been able to get the .galleryImgs click function working, but cant seem to get the #gallery-next click function to work. It's supposed to get the data-src attribute from the next .galleryImgs div and set it in the .galleryImg src. I've tried using addClass and removeClass so it's known which to start from but still wont work. All help appreciated.

```
<img class="galleryImgs" data-src="images/test-image-1.jpg" src="images/test-image-1-s.jpg" />
<img class="galleryImgs" data-src="images/test-image-2.jpg" src="images/test-image-2-s.jpg" />
<img class="galleryImgs" data-src="images/test-image-3.jpg" src="images/test-image-3-s.jpg" />
<img class="galleryImgs" data-src="images/test-image-4.jpg" src="images/test-image-4-s.jpg" />
<img class="galleryImgs" data-src="images/test-image-5.jpg" src="images/test-image-5-s.jpg" />

<img class="galleryImg" src="" />

<div id="gallery-next"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.galleryImgs').click(function(){
        $('.gallery').show();
        $(this).addClass('catherine');
        var $galleryImg = $(this).attr("data-src");
        $('.galleryImg').fadeIn().attr("src", $galleryImg);
    });
    $('#gallery-next').click(function(){            
        $('.galleryImgs').hasClass('catherine').removeClass('catherine').next('.galleryImgs').addClass('catherine');
        var $galleryImg = $('.galleryImgs').hasClass('catherine').attr("data-src");
        $('.galleryImg').attr("src", $galleryImg);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `catherine` is a very representative class name! +1

Comment: and now all the comments have disappeared...

Comment: The guy deleted his comment. But as I was saying, In fact I don't think any browser reloads the image when the src is changed which is the reason why I said you should change the way your slider worjks so as to scroll through the imags applying css to fade out the old one making it display none and fading in the new one.

Comment: Correction, it is supposed to, appears some browser do have hooks to understand

Comment: hmmm, if that's the case i'll code it the way I did the other by hiding the images and setting the copying the data-src value to the src value when clicked and then displaying them. Thanks for the help.

Comment: data-src is not how it is accessed in JQuery, it is `$('.galleryImgs').hasClass('catherine').data("src");`

Comment: data-src is a custom attribute i set to prevent the images from loading before they are called. anyway, having done some research and testing I've discovered a bug when using hasClass and removeClass together, which is a real bummer right now. figuring out an efficient way around it should be interesting.

Comment: data-src is an html5 attr not a custom one, jquery reads these as the data() global array: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
$('#gallery-next').click(function(){
        var $galleryImg = $('.galleryImgs.hidden').removeClass('hidden').closest('.galleryImgs').nextAll('.galleryImgs').eq(0).addClass('hidden').attr("data-src");
        $('.galleryImg').fadeIn().attr("src", $galleryImg);
    });
```

Comment: a bug is present when using hasClass and removeClass together, so I had to use an alternative method of getting the object with the desired class.

Answer (score 0):

As a courtesy I have rewritten your function:

```
$('#gallery-next').click(function(){       
    var el = $('.galleryImgs.catherine');
    if(el.length <= 0){
        console.log('something is really wrong...');
    }   
    el.removeClass('catherine').next('.galleryImgs').addClass('catherine');
    $('.galleryImg').attr("src", $('.galleryImgs.catherine').data('src'));
});
```

I edited this a tad, take the new code if you do.